# How to find all id attr with matching class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following `HTML` and I want to get all radio IDs which label class is `r_on` inside `<ul class="plan">...</ul>`

```
<ul class="plan">
    <li>
        <p>One Month</p>
        <label for="36" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="300" data-name="One Month" id="36" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>300 $</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Second Month</p>
        <label for="37" class="label_radio r_on">
            <input type="radio" value="600" data-name="Second Month" id="37" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>600$</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Third Month</p>
        <label for="38" class="label_radio r_on">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1200" data-name="Third Month" id="38" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>1200 $</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note: I want that result with comma separated string.

I want result like this: `37,38`

Any Idea how to do this with jQuery?

Comment: Why don't you want `36` in the result?

Comment: becouse there is no `r_on` class to 38

Comment: @Mr.Happy because there is no `r_on` class to `36`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var ids = $('.r_on :radio').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join();
```

Check the demo.

```js
var ids = $('.r_on :radio').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join();

alert(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="plan">
    <li>
        <p>One Month</p>
        <label for="36" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="300" data-name="One Month" id="36" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>300 $</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Second Month</p>
        <label for="37" class="label_radio r_on">
            <input type="radio" value="600" data-name="Second Month" id="37" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>600$</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Third Month</p>
        <label for="38" class="label_radio r_on">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1200" data-name="Third Month" id="38" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>1200 $</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = [];
    $('.r_on :radio').each(function() {
       ids.push(this.id);
    });
 alert(ids);
```

Check This Demo.

```js
var ids = [];
    $('.r_on :radio').each(function() {
   ids.push(this.id);
});
alert(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="plan">
    <li>
        <p>One Month</p>
        <label for="36" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="300" data-name="One Month" id="36" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>300 $</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Second Month</p>
        <label for="37" class="label_radio r_on">
            <input type="radio" value="600" data-name="Second Month" id="37" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>600$</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Third Month</p>
        <label for="38" class="label_radio r_on">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1200" data-name="Third Month" id="38" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>1200 $</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<ul class="plan">
    <li>
        <p>One Month</p>
        <label for="36" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="300" data-name="One Month" id="36" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>300 $</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Second Month</p>
        <label for="37" class="label_radio r_on">
            <input type="radio" value="600" data-name="Second Month" id="37" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>600$</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Third Month</p>
        <label for="38" class="label_radio r_on">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1200" data-name="Third Month" id="38" name="long-strip">
        </label>
        <strong>1200 $</strong>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
$('.plan .r_on input').each(function () {
    var ar = this.id;
  alert(ar);
});
</script>
```